# Private static file on next 13 app directory

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have two certificate files (.p12) that I need to use in a package. The issue at hand is that I haven't found any way to include them in the build and use them on the server. Including them in the 'public' folder is not recommended, and it wouldn't be functional either, as I would have to request the file over HTTP.

How would I go about doing this? I'm using Vercel to host my app, and during the build process, only the build itself is included, so leaving the .p12 files in the root folder wouldn't help either.

```
// src/lib/gn-sdk/index.ts
'use server';

import url from "url";
import path from "path";
import Gerencianet from "gn-api-sdk-typescript";
import { readdirSync } from "fs";
const { VERCEL_ENV, EFI_CLIENT_ID, EFI_SECRET } = process.env;

const certPath = url.pathToFileURL(
    path.join(
        process.cwd(),
        VERCEL_ENV == "production"
            ? "/.next/cert/production.p12"
            : "/.next/cert/development.p12"
    )
);

const gn = new Gerencianet({
    sandbox: VERCEL_ENV == "development",
    client_id: EFI_CLIENT_ID!,
    client_secret: EFI_SECRET!,
    certificate: certPath
});

// ...
```

update:
I tried to add a plugin to webpack so that during the compilation step, webpack would clone the folder where my .p12 files are located. I made sure that the plugin was being executed during the compilation, but still, the folder with the certificate files didn't exist when the runtime tried to access it.

I used readdir to read the folders generated by the build on Vercel and noticed that the build done on Vercel is different from the build done on my local machine, even though I have configured the project to use "npm run build."

next config:

```js
const nextConfig = {
    experimental: {
        serverActions: true,
    },
    webpack: (config, options) => {
        config.plugins.push(
            new CopyWebpackPlugin({
                patterns: [
                    {
                        from: "cert/*.p12",
                        to: process.cwd() + '/cert'
                    },
                ],
            })
        );

        return config;
    },
};
```